# Creating units in Cossacks more efficiently

Tags: cossacks-back-to-war

Is it possible to order units in Cossacks (e.g. Back to War, or Art of War), without having to click the corresponding "create button" for every single unit? It would be nice to just give a number to barracks, and wait for the creation of units to complete. Is there a way to do it?

It's not a problem to click when you want to create 50 additional units, but sometimes I want to create 500 additional units, and it is quite annoying to have to click once for every single one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to increase the amount by 5 per click.
Or hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to create infinite units.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer and shouldn't be down-voted.